# How to justify text to bottom of label?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uilabel

I created a label programmatically, which is important for my animation scene. Animation Scene takes text inputed by the user and displays it in the scene via typewriter like animation within label. The label height determines how much text i can add, the larger the height the more text. Since the text appears on the scene in a type writer fashion, as a new line of text is added, the previous line moves up.

How do I justify the text to the bottom of the label? I reviewed a bunch of similar questions via stackoverflow but non of the methods try to accomplish without storyboard.

```
func copyWithPacing(textToUse:String)->(){
        let TempTextHolder = textToUse
        var value: [Substring] = []
        var value1: [String] = []
        
        func updateAndAnimateSceneText () {
            
            let SceneMainlabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 400 , y: -70, width: 375, height: 500))
            SceneMainlabel.center = CGPoint(x: 190, y: 0)
            SceneMainlabel.textAlignment = .center
            SceneMainlabel.textColor = .black
            SceneMainlabel.text = ""
            SceneMainlabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: SceneMainlabel.font.pointSize)
            SceneMainlabel.numberOfLines = 5
            SceneMainlabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            
            print("text is finished compiling")
            self.view?.addSubview(SceneMainlabel)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1){
                let oneSpace = " "
                let twoSpacewithComma = " , "
                let oneSpacewithComma = " ,"
                let updateArray = TempTextHolder.replacingOccurrences(of: oneSpace, with: twoSpacewithComma)
                let splitArray = updateArray.components(separatedBy: oneSpacewithComma)
                
                //Delays
                for i in splitArray {
                    value.append("\(i)")
                    // SceneMainlabel.text! += "\(i)"
                    let count = SceneMainlabel.text!.components(separatedBy: " ").count
                    
                    //  delay at the 6th word space
                    if count == 6 {
                        print(count)
                        print(SceneMainlabel.text!)
                        RunLoop.current.run(until: Date()+0)
                        for b in i {
                            value1.append("\(b)")
                            SceneMainlabel.text! += "\(b)"
                            RunLoop.current.run(until: Date()+0.01)
                        }
                         
                    } else {
                        RunLoop.current.run(until: Date()+0.03)
                        for b in i {
                            value1.append("\(b)")
                            SceneMainlabel.text! += "\(b)"
                            RunLoop.current.run(until: Date()+0.05)
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 8){
                SceneMainlabel.removeFromSuperview()
                print("labeled remove")
            }
        }
        return updateAndAnimateSceneText ()
        
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide more code?

Comment: You can't change it. It's always centered vertically. What you need to do is change the frame's height so that it hugs the label, then move the frame down.

Comment: @Kudos okay added more code and detail

Comment: @aheze okay, this should work, hoping there was something more clear cut. Thank you.

Comment: This has been answered in the comments, hasn't it?